# Amazon Rekognition : AccessDeniedException , User is not authorized to perform: rekognition:DetectText

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-rekognition

Iam trying to use Text Detection and run a sample code to understand how it works.
My code is as follows:

Code passing the image in Bytes format gives the error:

`botocore.errorfactory.AccessDeniedException: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the DetectText operation: User is not authorized to perform: rekognition:DetectText because no identity-based policy allows the rekognition:DetectText action`

The code is :

```
from PIL import Image
import io
local='Dauntless.jpg'
client = boto3.client('rekognition', region_name='region name here',aws_access_key_id="keyId here",aws_secret_access_key="key here")
image = Image.open(local)

stream = io.BytesIO()
image.save(stream,format="JPEG")
image_binary = stream.getvalue()

response = client.detect_text(Image={'Bytes':image_binary})
print(response)
```

I tried another code as follows which also returns the same error.

```
import boto3

def detect_text(photo, bucket):

    client=boto3.client('rekognition', region_name='name 'here ,aws_access_key_id="key here",aws_secret_access_key="key here")

    response=client.detect_text(Image={'S3Object':{'Bucket':bucket,'Name':photo}})

    textDetections=response['TextDetections']
    print ('Detected text\n----------')
    for text in textDetections:
            print ('Detected text:' + text['DetectedText'])
            print ('Confidence: ' + "{:.2f}".format(text['Confidence']) + "%")
            print ('Id: {}'.format(text['Id']))
            if 'ParentId' in text:
                print ('Parent Id: {}'.format(text['ParentId']))
            print ('Type:' + text['Type'])
            print()
    return len(textDetections)

def main():

    bucket='bucketname'
    photo='Dauntlessss_52a311a2-884a-4bcb-ba29-d705c5a2ea12.jpg'
    text_count=detect_text(photo,bucket)
    print("Text detected: " + str(text_count))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Both the codes return the same error.
Any help as to what am i missing here ? Iam new to AWS.

Comment: How are you running this code?

Comment: Also, where are you running this code?

Comment: @Myz Iam running the code on the linux terminal.

Comment: Are you running this on any EC2 instance?

Comment: @Myz The credentials iam using are of an EC2 instance yes. S3 Bucket

Comment: Is there any IAM role attached to your EC2 instance? If yes, then you need to check permissions for this IAM and make sure that rekognition:DetectText is allowed for this role. If there is no IAM role attached, you will need to create an IAM role (with required permissions) and attach it to your EC2 instance.

Answer (score 2):

The proper policy/permission was not applied.

Please read the Amazon Rekognition identity-based policy properly.
The following example grants full access to Amazon Rekognition resources.

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "rekognition:*"
                ],
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Aws tutorial Link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/security_iam_id-based-policy-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

To call TextDetect operation, an identity-based policy needs to be defined that allows the Rekognition DetectText action - `rekognition:DetectText`.

A minimum policy requirement can be the following:

```
{
  "Sid": "RekognitionDetectText",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "rekognition:DetectText"
  ],
  "Resource": "*"
}
```

Based on what types of actions you wanted to use, feel free to grant more permissions accordingly. An example, I wanted to detect labels and moderation. The following policy can be defined:

```
{
  "Sid": "Rekognition",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "rekognition:DetectModerationLabels",
    "rekognition:DetectLabels",
    "rekognition:DetectText"
  ],
  "Resource": "*"
}
```